# Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I'm getting this exception while initializing the spring context.

I can confirm that I'm only using one spring version i.e. 5.3.3.

When I remove,

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
```

from xml then no errors related to this.
Also the same applicationContext.xml file is working in another branch.

```
2021-07-13 05:05:01,832 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121) DEBUG [4] (07/13/21 06:05:01:832): Startup Bean Invocation: 0 failed
2021-07-13 05:05:01,833 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121) EXCEPTION [3] (07/13/21 06:05:01:833): org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface: Exception occurred invoking Server Startup Bean
2021-07-13 05:05:01,835 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
2021-07-13 05:05:01,835 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:417)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.__refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,836 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:40002)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,837 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:676)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,837 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:558)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,837 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:41010)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,837 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,837 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
2021-07-13 05:05:01,837 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 121)   at com.prescient.stnmm.server.beans.BeanAccess.<init>(BeanAccess.java:124)
```

Comment: do you have 'spring-webmvc' dependency?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace, using code tags. Also how do you run/deploy this application? (I suspect you are deploying to Oracle WebLogic).

Comment: yes 'spring-webmvc' dependency is there.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have bean jar file which is part of ear and deploying that on Jboss EAP 7.2

Comment: Their lies your problem. You have the same jar in both the ear as the war. Leading to classloading issues (the same class in different classloaders isn't the same class, hence an error).

Comment: @M.Deinum If you see the ear structure all the library files are stored in APP-INF/lib and no duplication of jar files.

Comment: It isn't about the `APP-INF/lib` you probably have a WAR file in there too which also has jars (the same ones) leading to this issue.

Comment: Also make sure you have the   `spring-context` jar available in your classpath else it won't load anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are correct I'm initializing the beans defined in a jar from a war file and that war also has a 'spring-webmvc' dependency. I removed it and working fine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my perspective I think that there is internal confusion dependency versions even though you are using only one version... Which led to difficulties and conflicts between dependencies.

Make sure you checked all the versions of dependencies you have locally. Anyways I'm still researching about better answers to this.

Comment: Yes you are correct both my maven project has 'spring-webmvc' as a dependencies and that is causing confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the ear structure of my application
'sample.jar'
'firstWar'
'secondWar'

In sample.jar file i have defined beans which I'm initializing from the 'secondWar.war' project. Both the project i.e. sample.jar and 'secondWar.war' has same dependency i.e. 'spring-webmvc' this is causing the confusion. Removed this dependency from 'secondWar.war' and it is working now**